# How do I mark email as read when put into Archive on Outlook?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using macOS `10.12.1` with Outlook `15.28.1`.

Is there a setting or simple solution to mark emails as read when I archive them?

For now, I know I'm able to:

- Mark as read with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- Move to Archive with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> then typing `ar` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I'd like to only need to be concerned with getting my emails into the Archive and not have to go through the step of marking them as read.

Comment: I'm shocked that Outlook is completely missing this extremely basic feature. Can't find it no matter where I search.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Office  & Business 2016.  You can create a "Quick Step" by right clicking on the email in a list >> "create new," the "add action(s)."  To do this, I created an action to "mark as read," then added another action to "moved to folder" (indicating the Archive folder), then made a shortcut key for it.  It's that easy.

Comment: A screenshot would make this a great answer :-)